# How can I use strokedashoffset in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a hunger indicator, but `stroke-dashoffset` doesn't work, and the whole code starts glowing red.

Can you tell me how to implement this?

```
<Draggable id="player-needs" className="phud-needs">
<div className="needs-box">
<div className="circle">
<svg className="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="45" height="64" viewBox="0 0 210 210" >  

<circle  id="circ" transform="rotate(-90 105 105)" cx="105" cy="105" r="100" style={{strokedashoffset: this.state.drink}} />
</svg>
</div>
</div>
</Draggable>
```

Comment: it doesn't work that way, but if I write stroke-dashoffset the whole code begins to glow red

Comment: strokeDashOffset  did not help, the circle remains full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use the SVG `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` props in React.

The actual effect you want might be different, and could be better implemented with e.g. an SVG arc path.

```js
function Component() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(33);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const ival = setInterval(() => setCount(c => c + 1), 50);
    return () => clearInterval(ival);
  }, []);
  const perc = count % 100;
  const rest = 100 - perc;
  return (
    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" style={{width: "300px"}}>
      <circle
        cx="100"
        cy="100"
        r="80"
        fill="none"
        stroke="red"
        strokeWidth="5"
        strokeDashoffset={-perc}
        strokeDasharray={`${perc} ${perc}`}
      />
    </svg>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
```